# How to avoid the extra column used for ordering in the SELECT statement to the final output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, sql-server-2017

I have a table TestTable with columns `ID, Workitem_Type, [STATUS], Workitem, CompletedDate, WORK, Log_createdDate`

The data looks like:

```
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
| ID | Workitem_Type | STATUS | Workitem  |     CompletedDate       | WORK  |     Log_createdDate     |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem1 | 2019-12-19 01:20:35.060 | Work1 | 2014-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  2 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem2 | 2019-12-19 01:20:35.060 | Work2 | 2015-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  3 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem3 | 2019-12-17 01:20:35.060 | Work3 | 2018-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  4 | Request       | Pass   | Workitem4 | 2019-12-18 01:20:35.060 | Work4 | 2017-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  5 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem5 | 2019-12-17 01:20:35.060 | Work5 | 2016-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
```

I have to give priority based on `Workitem_Type`, `CompletedDate` and should order by the same priority and `Log_createdDate` in single query. So the output should look like the below:

```
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
| ID | Workitem_Type | STATUS | Workitem  |      CompletedDate      | WORK  |     Log_createdDate     |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem1 | 2019-12-19 01:31:12.620 | Work1 | 2014-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  2 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem2 | 2019-12-19 01:31:12.637 | Work2 | 2015-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  5 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem5 | 2019-12-17 01:31:12.637 | Work5 | 2016-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  3 | Remainder     | Pass   | Workitem3 | 2019-12-17 01:31:12.637 | Work3 | 2018-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
|  4 | Request       | Pass   | Workitem4 | 2019-12-18 01:31:12.637 | Work4 | 2017-12-17 00:36:38.557 |
+----+---------------+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------+
```

I tried with the below query:

```
SELECT  *, CASE WHEN Workitem_Type = 'Remainder' THEN 
               CASE WHEN CompletedDate > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
           ELSE 3 END AS [Priority] 
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY [Priority], Log_createdDate;
```

But I **don't want the `Priority` column to get appear in my output**. So Is there anyway to get the above output without priority column in single query?

Please find the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4160265bd7ea74e4b4a35598b99d1897) for the same.

Comment: Then don't put it (`Priority`) in your `SELECT` and just put the expression in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Larnu But I need the ordering based on the Priority column

Comment: Yes, so put it, the expression, in the `ORDER BY` only. What you order by doesn't have to be in the `SELECT` (there are some caveats to that, but not with this query).

Comment: @Larnu Yes, using the `CASE WHEN` expression in `ORDER BY` solved my issue, as per sticky bit's answer. Thanks for your comment too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the expression directly in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT * 
       FROM testtable
       ORDER BY CASE
                  WHEN workitem_type = 'Remainder' THEN 
                    CASE
                      WHEN completeddate > getdate() THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        2
                    END 
                  ELSE
                    3
                END,
                log_createddate;
```

EDIT:  (by gordon)

You don't need to nest the `CASE` expressions:

```
   ORDER BY (CASE WHEN workitem_type = 'Remainder' AND completeddate > getdate()
                  THEN 1
                  WHEN workitem_type = 'Remainder' 
                  THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
             END),
            log_createddate;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I expected using single query (without sub-query). I will accept in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You may enclose the query in a subquery and explicitly list the fields you wish to select, such as:

```
SELECT ID, Workitem_Type, STATUS, Workitem, CompletedDate, Work, Log_createdDate
FROM (
SELECT  *,CASE WHEN Workitem_Type = 'Remainder' THEN 
        CASE WHEN CompletedDate > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
    ELSE 3 END as [Priority] 
FROM TestTable
) as a
ORDER BY [Priority],
         Log_createdDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery like :

```
select ID, Workitem_Type, STATUS
    , Workitem, CompletedDate
    , WORK, Log_createdDate 
 from (SELECT  *, CASE WHEN Workitem_Type = 'Remainder' THEN 
               CASE WHEN CompletedDate > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
           ELSE 3 END AS [Priority] 
       FROM TestTable
      ORDER BY [Priority], Log_createdDate)
```